# many to many table should have only delete/insert operation - Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In sql database, why should many to many table have only delete/insert operation? For example: if we need to update one record, my project manager want me to deleted existing one and insert new record. Asked me not writing update command. Why?

Comment: Have you asked him?

Comment: I think the idea is that each row in such a relationship table maps from one entity to another using their respective keys and those key values rarely if ever change (e.g. when I re-marry am I simply changing the identity of my wife?!). It's a slightly picky point because an update is logically equivalent to a delete followed by an insert!

Answer (score 0):

Your manager might have experience with bad update statements being executed, there is no way to rollback them and all of the data is lost at once. There is no need to delete and then create new, but you can convince him to use Transactions. The thing is you need to be extremely careful and sure what are you doing when executing one